# How to use a bluetooth microphone and a built-in speaker at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth, microphone

I'm trying to achieve a very simple task in iOS. I would like to get audio from a Bluetooth microphone and play the audio simultaneously using the built-in speaker.

Here is what I have right now. The app allows users to choose a speaker and a microphone source. However, whenever I pick a built-in speaker, the app will switch to a built-in microphone. And whenever I pick a Bluetooth microphone, the app will use the Bluetooth speaker. There is no way I can use the Bluetooth microphone and the built-in speaker separately.

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession()
    var routePickerView = AVRoutePickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 50))
    let bus = 0
    var isRunning = false

    @IBOutlet weak var viewHolder: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpAVRoutePicker()
        setUpAVSession()
    }

    func setUpAVRoutePicker() {
        viewHolder.addArrangedSubview(routePickerView)
    }

    func setUpAVSession() {
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .allowAirPlay])
            try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.default)
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Error setting up AV session!")
            print(error)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func start(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        isRunning = !isRunning
        sender.setTitle(isRunning ? "Stop" : "Start", for: .normal)

        if isRunning {
            engine.attach(player)

            let inputFormat = engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: bus)

            engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputFormat)

            engine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 512, format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
                self.player.scheduleBuffer(buffer)
            }

            do {
                try engine.start()
            } catch {
                print("Engine start error")
                print(error)
                return
            }
            player.play()
        } else {
            engine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: bus)
            engine.stop()
            player.stop()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func onInputBtnClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Select Input", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)

        for input in audioSession.availableInputs ?? [] {
            controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: input.portName, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { action in
            do {
                try self.audioSession.setPreferredInput(input)
            } catch {
                print("Setting preferred input error")
                print(error)
            }
            }))
        }
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

It seems like it's impossible to achieve that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24519938/6308776), which is kinda crazy. I know that it's possible to achieve such a simple task on Android, but it looks like it's not possible for iOS. Does anyone have any ideas?

p/s: I would like to use a Bluetooth headset, and I don't want to have the transmission via wifi.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62954

> ... if an application is using setPreferredInput to select a Bluetooth
>   HFP input, the output should automatically be changed to the Bluetooth
>   HFP output corresponding with that input. Moreover, selecting a
>   Bluetooth HFP output using the MPVolumeView's route picker should
>   automatically change the input to the Bluetooth HFP input
>   corresponding with that output. In other words, both the input and
>   output should always end up on the same Bluetooth HFP device chosen
>   for either input/output even though only the input or output was set
>   individually. This is the intended behavior, but if it's not happening
>   we definitely want to know about it.

Comment: Are there any ways to achieve the intended behavior without using AVAudioSession at all?

Comment: These might help you:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2091/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003118-CH1-SCOPES
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatsinCoreAudio/WhatsinCoreAudio.html

Comment: Have you tried something like that before? Is it even possible with iOS?

Comment: Every implementation I've used always pairs the input with the output -- on purpose. It does look like there is a Hardware Abstraction Layer that may let you change it, but even it may assign them together.

Comment: I tried to achieve the same behavior using AVAudioSession but couldn't reach it. Is there any way to do that?